# Add attributes to laravel post

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I'm working on laravel e-commerce project where I need to add Attributes to my posts (image below as example)

[image: sample]

My question is how to achieve that? should i create new tables or can I add manually from `post.create` like any other e-commerce cms?

> Personally I prefer to be able to add fields in `post.create` like I
>   add `+` button and each time I click on it 2 input fields add and I
>   can put key and value in it. (if you can help me with that)

Thanks.

**Update:**

With suggest of @anas-red I've created this structure now:

`attributes` table.

```
Schema::create('attributes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

and `product_attributes` table

```
Schema::create('product_attributes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
            $table->integer('attribute_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('attribute_id')->references('id')->on('attributes');
            $table->string('attribute_value')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

now i have this store method on my controller when i save my posts:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
      //Validating title and body field
      $this->validate($request, array(
          'title'=>'required|max:225',
          'slug' =>'required|max:255',
          'user_id' =>'required|numeric',
          'image_one' =>'nullable|image',
          'image_two' =>'nullable|image',
          'image_three' =>'nullable|image',
          'image_four' =>'nullable|image',
          'image_one' =>'nullable|image',
          'short_description' => 'nullable|max:1000',
          'description' => 'nullable|max:100000',
          'subcategory_id' => 'required|numeric',
          'discount' => 'nullable|numeric',
          'discount_date' => 'nullable|date',
          'price' => 'required|numeric',
        ));

      $product = new Product;

      $product->title = $request->input('title');
      $product->slug = $request->input('slug');
      $product->user_id = $request->input('user_id');
      $product->description = $request->input('description');
      $product->short_description = $request->input('short_description');
      $product->subcategory_id = $request->input('subcategory_id');
      $product->discount = $request->input('discount');
      $product->discount_date = $request->input('discount_date');
      $product->price = $request->input('price');



      if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $filename = 'product' . '-' . time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $location = public_path('images/');
        $request->file('image')->move($location, $filename);

        $product->image = $filename;
      }


      $product->save();

      $product->attributes()->sync($request->attributes, false);

      //Display a successful message upon save
      Session::flash('flash_message', 'Product, '. $product->title.' created');
      return redirect()->route('admin.products.index');
    }
```

The process i want to do is this:

1. Store my attributes
2. Select my attributes while creating new post
3. Give value to selected attribute
4. save `post_id` `arribute_id` and `atteribute_value` in `product_attributes` table.

here is the error i get:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'attributes_id'
>   in 'field list' (SQL: select `attributes_id` from `product_attributes`
>   where `product_id` = 29)

**UPDATE:**

`Product` model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use jpmurray\LaravelCountdown\Traits\CalculateTimeDiff;

class Product extends Model
{
    use CalculateTimeDiff;

  protected $table = 'products';

  protected $fillable = [
      'title', 'slug', 'image_one', 'image_two', 'image_three', 'image_four', 'short_description', 'description', 'price', 'discount', 'discount_date',
  ];

  public function category(){
     return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
  }
  public function subcategory(){
     return $this->belongsTo(Subcategory::class);
  }

  public function attributes()
  {
     return $this->belongsToMany(Attribute::class, 'product_attributes', 'product_id', 'attribute_id');
  }

  public function order(){
     return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
  }

  public function discounts(){
    return $this->hasMany(Discount::class, 'product_id', 'id');
  }


}
```

`Attribute` model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Attribute extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = [
      'title',
  ];

  public function products(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
  }
}
```

Comment: Anyone can help with that?

Comment: #SOLVED# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46882735/how-to-save-sub-attribute-in-3rd-table-in-laravel

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add new table lets say "post_attributes" with the following columns:

```
id - post_id - key - value
```

in the PostAttribute model add this:

```
public function post
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Post::class); 
}
```

in the Post model add the following:

```
public function attributes 
{
   return $this->hasMany(PostAttributes::class, 'post_attributes'); 
}
```

Now the app is flexible enough to handle multiple attributes to one post or a single attribute to another.

Other approach is to implement JSON in your database. Hope that helped you.

Comment: Ok, it seems to be right but do you have solution for my second question? `Personally I prefer to be able to add fields in post.create like I add + button and each time I click on it 2 input fields add and I can put key and value in it. (if you can help me with that)`

Comment: yes you can do that. But you have to use javascript to add multiple attributes (key, value). Once you click submit the request will go to your controller. then in your controller you should iterate over all of them and save them to DB.

Comment: How come? Do you see any issue in that? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If I see your Product and Attribute Models I will be in a better position to answer you properly.

But any way, I think your problem is with the `product_attributes` table. 
This table is now acting as a pivot (intermediate) table and it is not following Laravel naming convention. The convention is to name it as follows: `attribute_product`.

Next, you have to add the following into both models i.e. `Product` and `Attribute`.

in Attribute Model add:

`$this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot('value');`

in Product Model add:

`$this->belongsToMany(Attribute::class)->withPivot('value');`

To add value to more_value column on pivot table. Use the following:

```
$product->attributes()->attach($attributeId, ['more_value' => $string]);
```

or use sync:

```
$product->attributes()->sync([$attributeId => ['more_value' => $string]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

update Product model

```
public function attributes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Attribute::class, 'product_attributes', 'product_id', 'attribute_id')->withPivot('attribute_value')->withTimestamps();
}
```

and update Attribute model to

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_attributes', 'attribute_id', 'product_id')->withPivot('attribute_value')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Comment: Ok bro now it saving integers but still can't save value https://imgur.com/a/Xiql5      `PS` I found out that using attribute name is not acceptable in laravel as using message is not acceptable for sending mails so I changed my attribute to other name for testing and I called it `more`! :)

Comment: Yes, I have doubts in this ```Attribute``` name also. But since you didn't mention any error I skipped it.

Answer (score 0):

lol. the important part is repo code is:

```
<input type="hidden" id="appOrderItems" name="orderItems[]">
```

trace appOrderItems in my JS section and you will get it.

in simple words:

when the user adds attributes to a product (in my case, items to an order) then, the appOrderItems array will get the id of the attribute and any additional value that you need to add into the pivot table (other than the product_id and attribute_id. in your case the mores_value). After gathering these attributes into appOrderItems JS array I push its value to the hidden HTML field (name="orderItems[]"). in this case it will be sent to the controller for further process.

Comment: OK now how i use your version of coding? seem to me many part that i don't need, probably in js as well.

Comment: you have to deal with JS to get an array containing your attribute_id and mores_value like so arrayOfAttributes = ['id' => 1, 'more_value' => 'attribute value 1'] and so on. I can't just give more info than that. You have to be able to read others' code, analyze, understand it and then implement youer own way in your code. Read mine, and if you don't understand any piece of code get back to me.

Comment: Hi bro, I'm trying another way here it is would you mind take a look at it?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46882735/how-to-save-sub-attribute-in-3rd-table-in-laravel