# How to save sub attribute in 3rd table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to save my `sub-attribute` data in `3rd` table but i got `Call to undefined method App\Product::mores()` error.

## Logic:

Getting `product_id` + getting `submore_id` save it to `product_mores` table.

## The issue:

The issue is that I don't want to get `more_id` but instead I want to get `submore_id`.

### hierarchy

1. More = CPU
2. Submore = Core i7
3. Product_id = 67

Result will be like:

[image]

Normally i should save attribute id and that would be easy with something like this:

```
$product->mores()->sync($request->mores, false);
```

after saving product **BUT** as I need to gave `submore` id I get error and it says:

```
Call to undefined method App\Product::mores()
```

which lead me to:

```
$product->mores()->sync($request->mores, false);
```

## Codes

create method:

```
public function create()
    {
      $categories = Category::all();
      $subcategories = Subcategory::all();
      $submores = Submore::all();
      $user = Auth::user();
      $brands = Brand::all();
      return view('admin.products.create', compact('user', 'categories', 'subcategories', 'submores', 'brands'));
    }
```

Store method:

```
//......
      $product->save();
      $product->mores()->sync($request->mores, false);

      //Display a successful message upon save
      Session::flash('flash_message', 'Product, '. $product->title.' created');
      return redirect()->route('products.index');
```

Create blade page:

```
  <label for="mores">Attributes</label>
  <select class="tagsselector form-control" name="mores[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option>Select Attribute</option>
    @foreach($submores as $more)
       <option value="{{ $more->id }}">{{ $more->title }}</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
```

Any idea?

Comment: You try to `sync` `mores` relation, but on your form you select them from  $submores collection. As i understand submores is relation in `mores`, am I correct? It's so confusing.. Could you provide structures of tables which you want to work with?

Comment: @f0rtis Already figure it out, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

All I needed was to add table and column names in my models functions like so:

```
public function submores()
  {
     return $this->belongsToMany(Submore::class, 'product_mores', 'product_id', 'submore_id');
  }
```

And also change my save function from `mores` to `submores` like so:

```
$product->submores()->sync($request->submores, false);
```

Then change the `name` and `for` in my form to `submores`

```
<label for="submores">Attributes</label>
<select class="tagsselector form-control" name="submores[]" multiple="multiple">
//// rest of the code...
```